# Resonant circuit in class C amplifier

Tags: amplifier, low-pass, resonance

**Questions**

1. What is the better option when maximum efficiency of class C amplifier is needed:

   - LC circuit between VCC and drain of amplifier + low pass filter
   - RF choke and low pass filter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fByCKs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Research**

In first option in the drain of the transistor there is a resonant LC circuit, in which the energy oscillates, which partially reduces the distortion of the input signal, and then there is a Low Pass Filter (LPF), which more accurately reduces the rest of the harmonics. Example: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gYbMpu4NoZo)

The second option seems to be more popular. It uses an inductor called RF choke (between the power supply and the drain), which provides a constant current. The transistor shorting the coil to ground increases the current in it, and then when the transistor is turned off, the current is flowing to the LPF circuit, which converts it into a sine wave. Example: [link](http://www.rfcandy.biz/communication/pa313.html#fun), [link](https://www.rcarc.org/presentations/AB2EW%20Class%20C%20club.pdf)

Comment: It entirely depends on what you are trying to achieve. Both have their places but those places are a little different so, what are your requirements? You can't reduce the distortion of the input signal BTW; it is what it is.

Comment: The LPF might have a shunt capacitor at the input, making the second equivalent to the first.

Comment: My goal in these questions is to understand which circuit in which situation is best to use.  Andy aka, could you elaborate on ' Both have their places'? This is what I'm interested in :)

Comment: C1 (parasitic capacitor) is always paralelled with L1. Idem with L2.

Comment: Antonio51 that is true, but C1 in my schematic is carefully chosen to make resonance at an amplifier working frequency. Only parasitic capacitance makes the circuit also resonate, but in complely diffrent frequency.

Comment: Not an expert but first one is more suitable when you hold M in linear region because of high cap inrush current. The second schematic for switched mode.